# Codeigniter object cache doesnt work

Tags: codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to save into the cache a json web response, my controller it's pretty simple, here's:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH . 'models/presenters/Radio.php';
use Streame\Model\Presenter\Radio as Radio;
use Streame\Model\Presenter\Genre as Genre;

class Test extends MY_Controller {


    public function index(){
        $this->load->driver('cache');
        if (! $cache_data = $this->cache->get('zzz')) {
            $req = $this->send_req('radios', 'GET', array("size" => 5, "phrase" => "rock"));
            $json = $req->json();
            $top_50_radios = Radio::deserializeJsonArray($json["docs"]);
            $cache_data = (object) $top_50_radios;
            $this->cache->save('zzz', $cache_data, 60 * 60 * 12);

            echo "\n</br>NOT CACHEEEEED"; var_dump($cache_data);
        } else {
            echo "\n</br>CACHEEEEED";  var_dump($cache_data);
        }
        shuffle($cache_data);
        $data["random_radio"] = $cache_data[0]->permalink;

    }

}
```

I got this working when I changed the `cache_path` in `config.php`, from nothing to this:

`$config['cache_path'] = APPPATH.'../../cache/';`

But now, from nowhere, It started to ignore the cache again, the only thing that I get is "NOT CACHED".

I'm running the framework in a nginx server, maybe has something to do with the permissions of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, `chmod 777 -R cache/` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if your problem goes away if you change the cache path config,
because it should work if you leave it blank (you should have within your application folder a cache folder)

the first thing what i would do is to check whether the variable is correctly saved or not

you can manage it if you insert

```
var_dump($this->cache->cache_info());
```

after you save the variable in the cache

if you get a correct information here - we are starting to get to the right direction - if not you have to check if your path really exists

Comment: it returns `boolean false` right after the `$this->cache->save('zzz', $cache_data, 60 * 60 * 12);`. I check that the folder existed and it does. I try changing the path to empty with no luck. I get rid of the .htaccess and index.html that I had in the cache folder, but didn't work.

Comment: What could mean the `cache_info` method returning false??